# Merge cell in datagridview in winform using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to create a scheduler for my projects.

For different time slots I have to show related information so there is a need to merge cells of datagridview.

Is there any third party tool avalable for this or I have to paint each required set of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to merge cells with the datagridview control is to use custom painting.

I'm not aware of any third party control libraries that have this functionality, but a good place to start looking would be the Telerik controls - their WinForms Grid Control looks like it supports cell merging, though I haven't used it.